# Validation date input - min and max value

Tags: javascript, html, date, input

I have one little problem with HTML5.

```
<input type="date" id="birthday" />
```

I want check this field in JavaScript.

Min. value - 01-01-1990.

I have no idea how to parse the date object and check that is correct.

Attribute min and max in HTML5 is not working. I must write validation in JavaScript.

Comment: check this: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Comment: input type="text" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a JavaScript validation library, which uses the HTML5 input attributes like min and max: for example [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/):

```
<input id="mydate" name="mydate" type="date" min="2000-01-01" max="2010-31-12" required />

<script>
    $("#mydate").validate();
</script>
```

Have a look as this fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/a5Mvt/1/

In addition you might want to use a library like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to check for browser support of `input[type="date"]` and use a datepicker control from [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or something similar, if it is not supported.

---

**Update:** Here's a version, that doesn't use jQuery or any other additional library:

```
<input id="mydate" name="mydate" type="date" min="2000-01-01" max="2010-31-12" required />
<span id="mydate_error" style="display:none;"></span>

<script>
    var mydate = document.getElementById('mydate'),
        mydateError = document.getElementById('mydate_error');

    mydate.addEventListener('input', function() {
        if (!mydate.value.match(/\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/)) {
            mydateError.innerHTML = 'Please specify a valid date in the form 1990-02-22';
            mydateError.style.display = 'inherit';
        } else {
            var value = new Date(mydate.value),
                min = new Date(mydate.min),
                max = new Date(mydate.max);
            if (value < min || value > max) {
                mydateError.innerHTML = 'Date has to be between ' + min.toDateString() + ' and ' + max.toDateString();
                mydateError.style.display = 'inherit';
            } else {
                mydateError.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a5Mvt/2/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the jQuery. I have everything written in JavaScript.
Works everything except the field.

Link:
http://www.iem.pw.edu.pl/~witkowr1/cwiczenie2/cwiczenie2.html

I have to make a check login with the database using Ajax, but it later;)

Comment: I just added a version without jQuery. If you need support for IE you may need to provide an alternative for addEventListener. And of course you need to verify the input on the server. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much ;) After little modification all working good. Sorry for my bad english, but I hope that you understand everything :)

Comment: Your 31-12 order is backwards.  "Set the value to a valid date string using the YYYY-MM-DD pattern defined in RFC3339."