# HTML5 Date Validation

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I'm looking to implement validation for a mobile site, where I have two input fields and I would like the first to validate the value is no later than todays date, and the second to validate it is no later than a one year in advance of the first value.

E.g

- First Value = 26/11/2013
- Second Value can not contain a value later than 26/11/2014

Is this possible?

Comment: You need to use jqury Scripts. HTML5 no Option

Comment: @Deekey Not necessarily jQuery, only Javascript.

Comment: Check date comparison using Javascript : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation date input - min and max value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773931/validation-date-input-min-and-max-value)

Comment: Don't use a regular expression for this, just JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It makes it easier to deal with dates and times.

First, let's make sure a day "is before tomorrow". This will depend a bit upon what the definition of tomorrow is.

```
var m = moment("26/11/2013", "MM/DD/YYYY");
// tomorrow this time
var t = moment().add("days", 1);
// tomorrow start of day
var tomorrow = moment([t.year(), t.month(), t.date()]);
if (m.lessThan(tomorrow)) {
   // today!!! (or before)
}
```

Similarly, the same approach can be used for a year from now. It's likely fine enough to not care about the time component in this case, and I've slogged on another day - but if it matters (e.g. looking for the start of the day), see the previous example.

```
var m = moment("26/11/2013", "MM/DD/YYYY");
var aYearFromNow = moment().add("years", 1).add("days", 1);
if (m.lessThan(aYearFromNow)) {
   // still less than a year!
}
```

Comment: Nice, can you pass a date object as the date and not just a string?

Comment: @PI. Sure. The [documentation is pretty good](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/).

Answer (score 1):

1) cache the elements.

```
var d1 = document.getElementById('date1');
var d2 = document.getElementById('date2');
```

2) The value of `d1` and `d2` are **`string`** data type.  So split them and parse it to date format as below

```
var t = d1.value.split("-");
var date = new Date(parseInt(t[0], 10) + 1, parseInt(t[1], 10), t[2]);
```

*Here the year is incremented by 1, based on the value in `d1`*.

4) Again parse it back to string format (YYYY-MM-DD)

```
var maxi = date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDate();
```

5) Set this as value for **`max`** attribute for `d2`

```
d2.setAttribute("max", maxi);
```

Finally add the below method to **`onblur`** event of **`d1`**.

```
function setMaxDate() {
    var d1 = document.getElementById('date1');
    var d2 = document.getElementById('date2');
    var t = d1.value.split("-");
    var date = new Date(parseInt(t[0], 10) + 1, parseInt(t[1], 10), t[2]);
    var maxi = date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDate();    
    d2.setAttribute("max", maxi);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/N5V4g/)

Answer (score 0):

Better with javascript. You can I use HTML5 attribute *type="date"* but keep in mind it's [barely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regex pattern like this `/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})/`, that is, two decimal digits, a slash, two more decimal digits, a slash and four decimal digits, everything grouped separately (group 1 = day, group 2 = month, group 3 = year). You would test for this pattern in a event, (I would suggest `onchange`, since you mentioned mobile) and also check if the numbers are within a valid range (e.g. day < 32, month < 13, year < currentYear-1).